# PowerShell to enumerate all Excel files in a document library that have links

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell

Can anyone advice on approaches to enumerating a given document library for any Excel files that have links? as a bonus, it would be great if I could also know what other files they link to.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By PowerShell, you could loop through all excel files and download the excel files in the document library.  Then read the data in the excel file to check if there are links.

More references:

[PowerShell: Download Documents/Files from SharePoint OnPrem.](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/harmeetw/2017/07/21/powershell-download-documentsfiles-from-sharepoint-onprem/)

[Download All Files From a SharePoint Library Programmatically using PowerShell.](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2013/06/download-all-files-from-library-programmatically-using-powershell.html)

[Integrating Microsoft Excel with PowerShell: Reading Data](https://www.petri.com/export-to-excel-with-powershell-part-3)

[PowerShell - Read an Excel file using COM Interface.](https://lazywinadmin.com/2014/03/powershell-read-excel-file-using-com.html)

Comment: Hi @Amy_MSFT, I don't want to download all the files as there could be potentially hundreds of thousands of Excel files.

Comment: I am afraid that we cannot read the excel content if we do not download the excel files by PowerShell.